# Kendo-Scheduler: How can I make agenda view limit to 7 days?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is it possible to limit the Kendo-Scheduler agenda view to only 7 days (e.g. from Monday to Sunday) as opposed to Monday - Monday for instance?

Week View
[image]

Agenda View
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
views: [
          { type: "week" },
          { type: customAgenda, title: "Agenda" }
],

var customAgenda = kendo.ui.AgendaView.extend({
        endDate: function () {
            var date = kendo.ui.AgendaView.fn.endDate.call(this);
            return kendo.date.addDays(date, 7); // take the date and add 7 next days
        }
    });
```

You need to be sure that *var date* is the Monday that you want to show.
For instance:

> var date = Mon Mar 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)